# Implementing streaming response for OpenAI's GPT 3.5 Turbo API in Android using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, streaming, openai-api

How can I implement streaming response for OpenAI's GPT 3.5 Turbo API in my Android chatbot app? Currently, I am using Retrofit to get the API response, but it takes around 15 to 20 seconds. I would like to optimize the response time by implementing streaming. Here is my current code for getting the API response:

```
public void callAPI(String question) {
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClientBuilder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Set the connect timeout
    httpClientBuilder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Set the read timeout
    httpClientBuilder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Set the write timeout

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.openai.com/v1/")
            .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ChatApiService chatApiService = retrofit.create(ChatApiService.class);

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("model", "gpt-3.5-turbo");
        jsonBody.put("max_tokens",4000);
        jsonBody.put("temperature",0);
        jsonBody.put("stream",true);
        JSONArray messageArray = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject userMessage = new JSONObject();
        userMessage.put("role", "user");
        userMessage.put("content", question);
        messageArray.put(userMessage);

        JSONObject assistantMessage = new JSONObject();
        assistantMessage.put("role", "assistant");
        assistantMessage.put("content", SharedPreference.getString(context, BaseUrl.Key_last_answer));
        messageArray.put(assistantMessage);

        jsonBody.put("messages", messageArray);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonBody.toString());

    Call<ResponseBody> call = chatApiService.getChatResponse(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                    String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
                            .getJSONObject("message")
                            .getString("content");
                    mAnswer = result.trim();

                    // Handle the response
                    addResponse(mAnswer);
                    addToChatHistory();
                    speakAnswer();
                    SharedPreference.putString(context, BaseUrl.Key_last_answer, mAnswer);
                } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (response.code() == 429) {
                    addResponse("Oops, something went wrong. Please try again in a little while.");
                } else {
                    if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                        try {
                            addResponse("Failed to load response due to " + response.errorBody().string());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            addResponse("Failed to load response due to " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I tried implementing the OpenAI GPT 3.5 Turbo API in my Android chatbot app using Retrofit. However, the response time is around 15 to 20 seconds, which is too slow. To improve it, I want to implement streaming. I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement streaming and optimize the response time.

Any suggestions or code examples on implementing streaming for the GPT 3.5 Turbo API using Retrofit would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    First add this on your endpoint.
    
    @Streaming
    @POST("v1/chat/completions")
```

Update your response and read data as inputStream
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonBody.toString());

```
        Call<ResponseBody> call = chatApiService.getChatResponse(requestBody);
    
       call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    //            
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Process the streaming data
                        if (response.body() != null) {
                            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                            getData(bufferedInputStream);
                        } else {
                            showError(errorSomeThing);
                            defaultValues(message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        showError(errorSomeThing);
                        defaultValues(message);
                        // Handle unsuccessful response
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    showError(networkError);
                    defaultValues(message);
             
                }
            });
```

Create a Function which process your BufferedInputStream

```
 void getData(BufferedInputStream inputStream) {
        // Create a byte array to store the data read from the InputStream
        new Thread(() -> {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // Adjust the buffer size according to your needs
            int bytesRead;
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            // Read data from the InputStream into the buffer until the end of the stream is reached
            try {
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    // Process the data read from the buffer
                    // You can convert the byte array to a String if the data is text-based
                    String[] data = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).split("data:");
//                    Log.e("tramResponseArray", Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(data).toArray()));
                    for (String responseString : data) {
                        String tramResponse = responseString.trim();
                        if (!tramResponse.isEmpty()) {
//                            Log.e("tramResponse", tramResponse);
                            if (!tramResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("[DONE]")) {
                                OpenAIChatResponseModel openAIChatResponseModel = null;
                                try {
                                    openAIChatResponseModel = gson.fromJson(tramResponse, OpenAIChatResponseModel.class);
                                    if (openAIChatResponseModel != null && openAIChatResponseModel.getChoices() != null) {
                                        if (openAIChatResponseModel.getChoices().get(0).getDelta().getContent() != null) {
                                            content.append(openAIChatResponseModel.getChoices().get(0).getDelta().getContent());
                                            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                                    String resposnseString = content.toString();
                                            });
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        showError("Something went wrong. Please try again later.");
                                    }
                                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
//                                    Log.e("LocalizedMessage", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                }
                            } 
                        }

                    }
                }
           

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Handle any IOException that may occur during the reading process
            } finally {
                // Close the InputStream to release system resources
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Handle any IOException that may occur during the closing process
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```